# AlpacaJS - Disable buttons on array field

Tags: jquery, arrays, alpacajs

I'm looking at the [official documentation](http://www.alpacajs.org/docs/fields/array.html), but i did not find anything about disabling the top buttons of array object, is there any way to disable those buttons? I aslo tryed to set the param `toolbar` to `{}` or `null`, but the buttons are still there.
Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That part in blue are 2 differents components the **toolbar** and the **actionbar**. There's no way to remove them in alpaca documentation, but everything is possible, all you can do is to create a custom template for the actionbar and use a new option like :

```
"options": {
   "hideActionBar": true,
   ...
}
```

then in your custom template this is how to use your new option :

```
{{#if options.hideActionBar}} ... {{/if}}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/jn66k77r/) for this.